MIL-STD-1275E surge protection
I am building a protection circuit for MIL-STD-1275E,
and my manager says the circuit will not work and to figure it out.
now I have addressed all the 4 main events in said STD: the surge, the spikes, the transients and the reverse polarity.
Am I missing something?
Edit:
I have addressed reverse polarity a bit better than before

Edit 2:
So I have listened to Lundin, and Maybe this on is better, but I have a feeling (not yet wasted time on simulating and calculations) this is not optimal at all.


What's with the BJT? I don't understand its purpose let alone how it is supposed to work?

My manager told me that he will give me an answer eventually but first to try and figure this one out on my self.
about the BJT with the diode, about giving it more stability during temp fluctuations, plus reverse input protection so the FETs won't be saturated and leaking current.

I see. Hmm well have you actually addressed reverse polarity? In reverse D3 will conduct with some voltage drop and then you'll get a lower voltage on the Vcc pin than on the GND pin which the IC might not like at all.

@Ludin
Well I have actually, I will updated the post.

Huh, I don't see how the change made any difference in regards to D3? You've added additional TVS towards chassis (which is good practice in case of MIL EMC) but that won't help with reverse polarity. Also that TVS should probably be located before the PI filter - the idea is to have as short a return path to chassis as possible. For similar designs we used one bidirectional TVS towards chassis before the filter and a second one towards signal ground after the filter.

As for reverse polarity protection, the classic way would be to use a P channel MOSFET "in reverse". After the point where the fuse and the 2 TVS are located, you could place a PMOS with the body diode in series with the incoming supply and the gate towards ground with a pull-down. In case of reverse polarity, the gate will stop the part from conducting and the Vdd (which is now ground) will get disconnected, so no current flows through the circuit anywhere. This given that you only have a single point where ground/chassis is connected, otherwise it won't work.

Everything is fed by a battery, so naturally it is not really GND, but return.

Regarding comments about reverse polarity: this is the issue I tried to describe:

When signal ground turns into Vdd and Vdd turns into ground, The VCC pin of the surge stopper IC will get a voltage potential of Vdd minus the forward voltage of D3. Meaning lower potential than what's applied at the GND pin. There's a possibility of reverse currents there, which is usually a pretty certain way to kill an IC, even a rugged one like this.
The TVS won't act as polarity protection - rather they will just continously conduct until something burns out; not necessarily the TVS since they tend to be quite rugged and tolerate a lot of heat. Something else is likely to give first: the IC, or some trace, or the tantalum cap C7 etc etc.
Instead you could use the good old P MOSFET trick as described here: Reverse Polarity Voltage Protection Using P-MOSFET. (You probably don't need the Vgs protecting zener in this case.)

Unrelated to that issue, you should move the TVS D4 to the far left before the pi filter, to get as short a path towards chassis ground as possible. D5 towards signal ground can remain where it is. It is good to use bidirectional TVS in case you use the P MOSFET polarity protection too, since they won't overrule it like a unidirectional TVS would.

I have updated the circuit, have a look, I am eagerly waiting for your reply.

@Nightshade You should probably ask a new question about reverse polarity instead of updating this question over and over. Anyway, I don't think it is wise to place the MOSFET in the GND return path as you'll get the Rds(on) resistance in series with ground that way. And the schottky in series shouldn't be necessary either.

I will open one for the next update.
for now I chose nFET for ground due to very low Rds.
